# Shortest line network route between clusters of points and the cluster centroid

Tags: qgis, shortest-path, network-analysis, batch

[image: Example]
I have a point layer containing clusters of points (premises) that I have grouped using a clustering algorithm (the clusters each having their own unique ID which I have used to create convex hull polygon boundaries surrounding each group/cluster of points).

I have created another point layer containing the centroids of each of the cluster's polygon boundaries, and would like to use these centroid points to calculate the shortest line distance between each cluster's centroid and just their associated cluster points. I don't however, wish to calculate the distance between one cluster's centroid, and another cluster's points (i.e. the distance calculations need to be constrained within the polygon boundaries of each cluster).

I also need the distance to be the distance of the road network (which I have in the form of a line layer), rather than the straight line distance. Neither am I seeking to just find the closest premises to the cluster's centroid, I need to have the shortest road network distance for every point in the cluster, to the cluster's centroid. In addition, I would like to factor in the distance between the centroid/premises and the nearest point on the road network, where the centroid or premises is distant from the road network (i.e. in the case of a premises, there is a long private drive, or it is located down a dirt track). In such cases the straight line distance will suffice.

I can do this manually, selecting each cluster separately and running an algorithm, but there seems to be no way of restraining the calculations to each cluster if inputting all clusters as one layer. In other words the algorithm will just see one set of points (the premises) and another (the centroids), and compute the shortest distances between all of them across the entire road network, without stopping at the boundaries of each cluster.

Given I have over 60 clusters, I don't wish to split the clusters into 60 different layers and then run the algorithm 60 different times! Is there an easy way of batching this within QGIS 3.16.5? I'm currently using the QNEAT3 OD Matrix tools, but in the case of the example image, it just computes the distances between all clusters and their centroids, it doesn't look at the clusters in isolation.

Comment: You question/problem sounds clear to me. However, you could increase your chances to get a good answer adding the following elements: 1. adding a screenshot will make your question more attractive - instead of reading a long text, the basic settings can be seen at the first glance 2. adding sample data would help finding a solution - otherwise, you first have to build all the data yourself for testing purpose 3. telling us what algorithm you used or you intend to use for (individual) network analysis, to give a hint which algorithm produces the results you're looking for.

Comment: I've added a basic example, and mentioned the plugin I'm using